# Create jar of a java application where entry point is an external program

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins

I have a java plugin written for a software called icy. Since the entry point of program is when the plugin is activated from the software, I am having trouble about how to mention that in manifest.mf file. When I give the main class (which has event handler and not the main method) it says resources not found.

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 3):

Why do you want to "mention" anything in the manifest file?

What does the documentation of the software you're writing the plugin for say about what it expects in the manifest?

Most likely, you can just leave out the `Main-Class` header or even omit the manifest entirely.

Comment: When I select the class containing the event handler in launch configuration option it says it cant find the resource. I reckon it means it didn't find main method in it.

Comment: @SudipBhandari: I assume "launch configuration option" means  you're trying to launch it manually in eclipse. Why do that when it's an event handler for a plugin? For testing? In that case, simply add a main method.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should export your project as a regular jar file and not as a runnable jar. That way your plugin client just need to know what method to call just like when you use an API. The only difference is that that method will open a Window etc.